# Passing self as parameter in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

I would like to pass "self" as parameter to a method of another class (in a different unit). However the type of the first class is unknown in the second one, because I can't put the first unit into the uses section of the second unit. So I define the parameters type as pointer but when I try to call a method from the first class the Delphi 7 parser tells me that the classtyp is required.

So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a job for an interface.  As a kludge you are allowed circular references in the case where 'B' uses 'A' in the interface and 'A' uses 'B' in the implementation.  This is almost always a bad idea, mind.

Comment: What if declare second unit in uses of implementation section?

Comment: Just use a `TObject` as a parameter instead of a pointer and a parent for the first class.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky: I need the type of the second class in the first though.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Then you cannot refer to the class in the interface section

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it wasn't clear in the OP that *both* units had types that were required by each other.  In the simple case where 'A' declares a type that 'B's method must use and 'B' provides a method that 'A' must use then it works if 'B' uses 'A' in the interface and 'A' uses 'B' in the implementation.  If they both need to do this (as it seems from Itsstar's comment) then obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: You also have specific reasons to not move all code into one unit?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky everything in one unit quickly evolves into a 'Big Ball of Mud'

Comment: @mjn - circular references also end up in a 'Big Ball of Mud'

Comment: @J... maybe, but circular references are already an anti-pattern by itself, putting them in one single unit just doubles the "code smell" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Object-oriented_design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By making the class known in the implementaion part you can cast the given reference.

```
unit UnitY;

interface
uses Classes;
type
    TTest=Class
       Constructor Create(AUnKnowOne:TObject);
    End;



implementation
uses UnitX;
{ TTest }

constructor TTest.Create(AUnKnowOne: TObject);
begin
    if AUnKnowOne is TClassFromUnitX then
      begin
         TClassFromUnitX(AUnKnowOne).DoSomeThing;
      end
    else
      begin
         // .... 
      end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the interface approach for this type of problem.  Unless your units are very tightly coupled, in which case they should probably share a unit, interfaces are tidy ways of exchanging relevant parts of classes without having to have full knowledge of each type.

Consider :

```
unit UnitI;
interface
type
  IDoSomething = Interface(IInterface)
    function GetIsFoo : Boolean;
    property isFoo : Boolean read GetIsFoo;
  end;
implementation
end.
```

and

```
unit UnitA;
interface
uses UnitI;
type
  TClassA = class(TInterfacedObject, IDoSomething)
     private
       Ffoo : boolean;
       function GetIsFoo() : boolean;
     public
       property isFoo : boolean read GetIsFoo;
       procedure DoBar;
       constructor Create;
  end;
implementation
uses UnitB;

constructor TClassA.Create;
begin
  Ffoo := true;
end;

function TClassA.GetIsFoo() : boolean;
begin
  result := Ffoo;
end;

procedure TClassA.DoBar;
var SomeClassB : TClassB;
begin
  SomeClassB := TClassB.Create;
  SomeClassB.DoIfFoo(self);
end;

end.
```

and notice that `TClassB` does not have to know anything about `TClassA` or the unit that contains it - it simply accepts any object that abides by the `IDoSomething` interface contract.

```
unit UnitB;
interface
uses UnitI;
type
  TClassB = class(TObject)
    private
      Ffoobar : integer;
    public
      procedure DoIfFoo(bar : IDoSomething);
      constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

constructor TClassB.Create;
begin
  Ffoobar := 3;
end;

procedure TClassB.DoIfFoo(bar : IDoSomething);
begin
  if bar.isFoo then Ffoobar := 777;
end;

end.
```